# Possible scope issue, will not calculate correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope

I have been trying to debug and research this problem for the past three or four hours, still can't figure it out. It is most likely simple, as I don't know how to do much. Here is my code:

```
def main():
    endProgram = "no"
    endOrder = "no"
    totalFry = 0.0
    totalSoda = 0.0
    total = 0.0
    tax = 0.0
    subtotal = 0.0
    option = 0
    burgerCount = 0
    fryCount = 0
    sodaCount = 0
    while(endProgram == "no"):
        resetVariables(totalBurger, totalFry, totalSoda, total, tax, subtotal)
        while(endOrder == "no"):
            option =int(input("Enter 1 for Yum Yum Burger\nEnter 2 for Grease Yum Fries\nEnter 3 for Soda Yum"))
            if(option == 1):
                getBurger(totalBurger, burgerCount)
            elif(option == 2):
                getFry(totalFry, fryCount)
            elif(option == 3):
                getSoda(totalSoda, sodaCount)
            endOrder = input("Do you want to end your order?")
        calcTotal(totalBurger, totalFry, totalSoda, total, subtotal, tax)
        printReceipt(total)
        endProgram = input("Do you want to end the program?")

def resetVariables(totalBurger, totalFry, totalSoda, total, tax, subtotal):
    totalBurger = 0
    totalFry = 0
    totalSoda = 0
    total = 0.0
    tax = 0.0
    subtotal = 0.0
    return(totalBurger, totalFry, totalSoda, total, tax, subtotal)

def getBurger(totalBurger, burgerCount):
    burgerCount = float(input("Enter the number of burgers you want.\n\t"))
    totalBurger = totalBurger + burgerCount * .99
    return(totalBurger, burgerCount)

def getFry(totalFry, fryCount):
    fryCount = float(input("Enter the number of fries you want.\n\t"))
    totalFry = totalFry + fryCount * .79
    return(totalFry, fryCount)

def getSoda(totalSoda, sodaCount):
    sodaCount = float(input("Enter the number of sodas you want.\n\t"))
    totalSoda = totalSoda + sodaCount * 1.09
    return(totalSoda, sodaCount)

def calcTotal(totalBurger, totalFry, totalSoda, total, subtotal, tax):
    subtotal = totalBurger + totalFry + totalSoda
    tax = subtotal * .6
    total = subtotal + tax
    return(totalBurger, totalFry, totalSoda, total, subtotal, tax)

def printReceipt(total):
    print("Your total is: $", total)
    return(total)

main()
```

I do have everything indented correctly, I am just tired and to lazy to edit it. Whenever I run this, I input everything and it just says my total is $ 0.0, no matter what. It is not an error with a Traceback, so I cannot give that. Thanks for anything you can do to help. If you think this post has been previously answered, **please** post where you think it might help.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], not just your whole program. Cutting it down to this might help you find the issue yourself.

Answer (score 1):

In your `main` function, you call `calcTotal` but without storing the returned result. You may try to just return `total` at the end of `calctotal`, and in `main` you call instead

```
total = calcTotal(totalBurger, totalFry, totalSoda, total, subtotal, tax)
```